# Reduce size of installed ndk-bundle

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3, ndk-build

I have install `ndk-bundle` from `sdkmanager`. The ndk-bundle taking around 4.2GB.
The bundle has tools chains for different architectures and platforms. Is there a way to just install tool-chain for one particular platform and architecture? I would like to install only arm and aarch64 toolchains as part of ndk and for any one `android-{}` platform.

Answer (score 0):

There's no supported way to do this. You could try deleting the directories in `$NDK/toolchains` that *aren't* `llvm`, but no guarantee that won't break things.